How to resolve `missing blob` error when updating Homebrew?
I haven't been able to update Homebrew properly in several months.
Here are the results I get after the brew update command:
➜  ~ brew update             
==> Updating Homebrew...
error: Could not read bb632218e19f001228fdbdd632fd7ce027bf5a4a
fatal: missing blob object '5b31ddd5df5b26b66bb8d1abb655f01df261ef05'
error: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-bundle did not send all necessary objects

error: Could not read 2708973cc6ff7d88c36aa461c7614d6d1e6b8044
fatal: pack has 1 unresolved delta
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
error: Could not read 72c0a8f18e6cdfee674e46b78029cabdfb32eafb
error: Could not read 72c0a8f18e6cdfee674e46b78029cabdfb32eafb
fatal: pack has 679 unresolved deltas
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
Error: Fetching /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-bundle failed!
Fetching /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask-fonts failed!
Fetching /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask-versions failed!
➜  ~ 

I have searched high and low, and so far, nothing I've tried has resolved the issue.
Searching thru my terminal history … the problem may have started when I issued the following commands:
npm create svelte@latest myapp
sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/username/.npm"
npm create svelte@latest myapp
cd myapp
npm install
npm run dev

It appears that the first npm create failed.  I guess somewhere on the interweb I saw to try the chown command, after which the npm create did work.  The next time I tried to do brew update it failed.
Is there a way to preserve my taps, casks, and formulas and start over?
I have tried the following so far:
cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services && git stash pop

 cd /usr/local/Homebrew && git stash -u && git clean -d -f

cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask-versions && git stash -u && git clean -d -f

brew update-reset

git -C "/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core" fetch --unshallow
git -C "/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask" fetch --unshallow

cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/
rm -rf homebrew-core                                                              
git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core.git

IF chown was at fault, I don't know how to undo it.

Is this on topic? It seems like a matter of system administration rather than programming.
